# What decimal.js rounding mode matches lodash rounding?

Tags: javascript, lodash, rounding, decimal.js

I need to refactor [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#round) `_.round()` to use [decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/#toDP) `toDecimalPlaces()`

Which of the [decimal.js rounding methods](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/#modes) matches the way lodash rounds?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems rounding mode 7 which is `ROUND_HALF_CEIL` matches lodash _.round()

```
Decimal.set({rounding: Decimal.ROUND_HALF_CEIL});
console.log(Decimal.rounding,'Decimal.rounding');
// 7 'Decimal.rounding'
var test1 = Decimal(3.15).toDP(1).toString();
console.log(test1,'test1');
// 3.2 test1
var test2 = Decimal(-3.15).toDP(1).toString();
console.log(test2,'test2');
// -3.1 test2
var test3 = _.round(3.15, 1);
console.log(test3,'test3');
// 3.2 test3
var test4 = _.round(-3.15, 1);
console.log(test4,'test4');
// -3.1 test4
```

NOTE: this is not an exhaustive test.  I remember from experience modes 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, and 9 are not correct.